# Understanding $\|(x-p)\cdot {\hat {n}}\|=\|(x-p)^{\top }{\hat {n}}\|$.

Tags: geometry, vectors, analytic-geometry

I am looking at this [equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line%E2%80%93line_intersection#In_two_dimensions_2) that compute the distance from a point $x$ to a line defined by a point $p$ on the line and a normal vector $\hat{n}$ to that line.

$$
d(x,(p,n))=\|(x-p)\cdot {\hat {n}}\|=\|(x-p)^{\top }{\hat {n}}\|={\sqrt {(x-p)^{\top }{\hat {n}}{\hat {n}}^{\top }(x-p)}}.
$$

However, I am having trouble understanding its derivation, I was hopping that someone would provide a more detailed explanation for how to derive it.

Comment: yes, but only if the norm is the 2-norm (euclidean norm).

Comment: the 2 norm is the sum of squares of vector entries and then square root afterwards, so what you need to verify is that the matrix multiplication transposed by itself does indeed produce the sum of squares.

Comment: @mathreadler But the first term compute the norm of a scalar which is just the absolute value of the dot product while the second term compute the magnitude of a vector composed from the terms of the dot product which is clearly not equal to the first term. Am I understanding this wrong?

Comment: $(x-p)\cdot \hat n$ is a scalar yes, but maybe it turns out to be the same in the end anyway. Just assume the vectors have some scalars, for example $a_1,a_2,\cdots, a_n$ for first vector and $b_1,b_2,\cdots,b_n$ for second vector and do the evaluations and see for yourself.